# How to replace all value in all columns in a Pandas dataframe with condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame:

```
In [11]: import pandas as pd

In [12]: mydict = {'foo':[0, 0.3], 'bar':[1,0.55], 'qux': [0.3,4.1]}

In [13]: df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(mydict, orient='index')

In [14]: df
Out[14]:
       0     1
qux  0.3  4.10
foo  0.0  0.30
bar  1.0  0.55
```

What I want to do is to replace all values that is less than 1 with 0.
Yielding:

```
       0     1
qux  0     4.10
foo  0     0
bar  1.0   0
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use boolean indexing and pass the condition:

```
In [155]:
df[df<1] = 0
df
Out[155]:
     0    1
bar  1  0.0
foo  0  0.0
qux  0  4.1
```

Just to show what is happening here performing `df < 1` will return a boolean index:

```
In [156]:
df < 1
Out[156]:
         0      1
bar  False   True
foo   True   True
qux   True  False
```

This we then pass to `df` as a mask and can then assign the new values as `df[df<1]` see the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html#boolean-indexing) for further examples

Comment: How do you do this but not inplace?

Comment: @O.rka I don't understand your question, if you don't assign the result then doesn't mutate the df

Comment: A lot of the functions have inplace=False which doesn't change the original object. Is there a similar way with this?

Comment: @O.rka but there are no functions being called, you either assign to your df or you don't using `=`

Comment: @O.rka just for completeness. To not make it in place, create a copy of your dataframe. `dfc = df.copy()` and work with that.